# Attiny : Is it possible to analog read on PB1?

Tags: analogread, attiny, attiny85

I'm trying to read an analog input on the Attiny85 physical pin 6 (PB1, PWM), but analogRead(PB1) always returns 1023. Is it even possible to use analogRead on this pin?
I'm fairly new to this so sorry if it's an obvious answer.
Thanks!

Comment: section 10.3.1 https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

PB1 has no analog input. So no, you can't read analog with it.

For analog you must use any of PB2 through PB5.

Comment: oh shoot... alright, thank you for the quick answer!!